# ¿Existe relación entre la palabra "OJO" y su apariencia?

Tags: etimología

Me parece interesante que la palabra *ojo* aparente la forma de dos ojos y una nariz en medio. ¿Es esto mera coincidencia o la palabra se creó intencionalmente de esta forma para que tuviera este aspecto?

Comment: Interesante, nunca lo había notado

Comment: Problemente no. Viene del latín vulgar (_oculus_) y como en otras palabras la terminación "culus" derivó en "jo" (Por ejemplo veclus -> viejo)

Comment: Muchas veces en un aviso donde se indica que se debe prestart atencion a cierta cosa, se escribe la palabra "ojo" como un dibujito de dos ojos y una nariz.  Esto no tiene nada que ver con el origen de la palabra ni de su forma escrita.

Comment: +1, por los intereses metalinguísticos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como belisarius dijo antes: "Problemente no. Viene del latín vulgar (oculus) y como en otras palabras la terminación "culus" derivó en "jo" (Por ejemplo veclus -> viejo)".

Eso sí, algunas veces se dibuja sólamente porque queda un lindo efecto gráfico, nada que ver con el lenguaje en sí.

Answer (score 3):

**No, pero...**

La letra O proviene del dibujo de un ojo. Según [la Wikipedia inglesa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O):

> Its graphic form has remained fairly constant from Phoenician times until today. The name of the Phoenician letter was ʿeyn, meaning "eye", and indeed its shape originates simply as a drawing of a human eye (possibly inspired by the corresponding Egyptian hieroglyph, cf. Proto-Sinaitic script).

En la Wikipedia española aparece la evolución de la letra:

[image: Evolución de la O]

A esto se le une el hecho de que la palabra latina *oculus* proviene de una posible raíz proto-indo-europea *[*okw-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*okw-#etymonline_v_52718)*, que significaría "ver". Se cree que esta raíz dio también origen al proto-germánico **augon*, raíz del inglés *eye*. Como ves, dicha raíz contiene el sonido *o*.

Así pues, por una curiosa casualidad resulta que la palabra española para *ojo* se compone realmente de dos ojos, alrededor de una letra que parece una nariz. Pero respondiendo a tu pregunta, no, la palabra *ojo* no se derivó del hecho de que se asemeje a los ojos y la nariz, sino que derivó del latín *oculus* como ya se ha notado en otras respuestas y comentarios.